# What does this regular expression match

Tags: regex, perl

Can someone help me decode what this regular expression matches?

```
<(.*?)>
```

Comment: It should have probably been written as `<([^>]*)>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It captures the text portion of `tags` for example in the tag `<center>` the string `center` is captured.

```
<  # Match the literal < that denotes the start of a tag
(  # Start capture 
.* # Match everything
?  # Non-greed match 
)  # Stop capture
>  # Match the literal > that denotes the end of a tag
```

Answer (score 4):

Considered to look at the [documentation, e.g. Perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Matching-repetitions)?

`<` matches a literal "<"

`.` regex special character, matches every character except newlines

`*?` ungreedy quantifier, matches 0 or more, but as less as possible

`>` matches a literal ">"

`(...)` capturing group

So `<(.*?)>` matches from a "<" to the next ">" and the stuff in between is stored in the first capturing group, because of the brackets around.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Will refer the link provided as well, cheers!

Comment: Nice clear answer (finally.) So if this was used on xml or html etc it would capture the tag name and any attributes of an opening tag. It will also match and capture self closing tags like <br /> in html and plain closing tags. It would not work properly (as is) if someone stupidly split a html tag across two lines, which still would be ok for html but not for this regex. What the regex captures, whatever is inside the <> tag delimiters, is available in the variable $1 for your code to use.